# Crystal reports subtrack running total

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to create a formula for running total subtract sales from opening stock. I have database fields for Opening stock and sales. From opening stock I have to subtract sale and show from second record

For example:

```
    ID         openingstock      sales    Stockonhand
    ---        ------           -------  -------------
     1           500              10          500
     2                             5          490
     3                            10          485
     4                             3          475
     5                             5          472
```

Comment: May you show your schema?